# Output node for tensorflow graph created with tf.layers

Tags: tensorflow

I have built a tensorflow neural net and now want to run the `graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants` function on it. However this requires an `output_node_names` parameter. The last layer in the net has the name `logit` and is built as follows:

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=5, name='logit')
```

however there are many nodes in that scope:

```
gd = sess.graph_def
for n in gd.node:
    if 'logit' in n.name:print(n.name)
```

prints:

```
logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min
logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max
logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform
logit/kernel
logit/kernel/Assign
logit/kernel/read
logit/bias/Initializer/zeros
logit/bias
logit/bias/Assign
logit/bias/read
logit/Tensordot/Shape
logit/Tensordot/Rank
logit/Tensordot/axes
...
logit/Tensordot/Reshape_1
logit/Tensordot/MatMul
logit/Tensordot/Const_2
logit/Tensordot/concat_2/axis
logit/Tensordot/concat_2
logit/Tensordot
logit/BiasAdd
...
```

How do I work out which of these nodes is the output node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graph is complex, a common way is to add an identity node at the end:

```
output = tf.identity(logits, 'output')
# you can use the name "output"
```

For example, the following code should work:

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=5, name='logit')
output = tf.identity(logits, 'output')
output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    ss, tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), ['output'])
```